# Can't change php variables in joomla official docker container

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I am using the joomla official docker container. The problem is that I need to install a component but I receive the following error message:

`Maximum PHP file upload size is too small: This is set in php.ini in both upload_max_filesize and post_max_size settings of your PHP settings`

I known that I have to edit this php variables in order to install the component. I don't known where is the php.ini file. I already run the phpinfo() function and get the path for the php configuration file in

/usr/local/etc/php
The problem is there are no php.ini file.

How can I change these php variables? How to find the php.ini file in the official joomla docker container?

Comment: check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get this solution form stackoverflow:

> You will have to provide your own php.ini file, and load that to the
>   container as a volume. To do that, add the following flag to docker
>   run command:
>
> -v local/path/to/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini If you are using docker compose, update the volumes section of your joomla container
>   definition to look like so:
>
> joomla_container:
>       ...
>       volumes:
>         ...
>         - local/path/to/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini You definitely shouldn't try to edit the configuration in a running
>   container. If you'd do this, you'd loose all of your configuration
>   together with the running container instance when you want to, for
>   example, update the image.

The link for the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36425304/2486661

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I've never heard of Joomla Docker container before, which is OK, we all learn something new every day. Regarding your question, if your only problem is that Maximum PHP file upload size is too small, you might try alternative install method by expanding the extension installation archive file into a folder on your local machine, then uploading expanded content to /tmp folder of your site, and installing it from there, by using "Install from Folder" tab in `Extensions -> Manage -> Install`. Just enter the location where you uploaded files and click on "Install" button.

That way you don't need to chase php.ini file in Docker container.

Comment: Yes exists a official Joomla Docker container, and for those who known how to use docker it is the more rapid way of get a joomla instance running. You can get the container here: https://hub.docker.com/_/joomla/